# R slideview min example returns blank output

Tags: r, htmlwidgets

I'm using the CRAN version of [slideview](https://github.com/r-spatial/slideview) but the minimal example (below) only returns blank output on my machine. I've verified that `img2000` and `img2013` both plot, they just don't work within `slideView()`.

```
### example taken from
### http://www.news.com.au/technology/environment/nasa-images-reveal-
### aral-sea-is-shrinking-before-our-eyes/story-e6frflp0-1227074133835
library(jpeg)
library(raster)
library(slideview)

# 2000
web_img2000 <- "http://cdn.newsapi.com.au/image/v1/68565a36c0fccb1bc43c09d96e8fb029"
jpg2000 <- readJPEG(readBin(web_img2000, "raw", 1e6))

# Convert imagedata to raster
rst_blue2000 <- raster(jpg2000[, , 1])
rst_green2000 <- raster(jpg2000[, , 2])
rst_red2000 <- raster(jpg2000[, , 3])

img2000 <- brick(rst_red2000, rst_green2000, rst_blue2000)

# 2013
web_img2013 <- "http://cdn.newsapi.com.au/image/v1/5707499d769db4b8ec76e8df61933f2a"
jpg2013 <- readJPEG(readBin(web_img2013, "raw", 1e6))

# Convert imagedata to raster
rst_blue2013 <- raster(jpg2013[, , 1])
rst_green2013 <- raster(jpg2013[, , 2])
rst_red2013 <- raster(jpg2013[, , 3])

img2013 <- brick(rst_red2013, rst_green2013, rst_blue2013)

slideView(img2000, img2013, label1 = "before", label2 = "after")
```

Comment: The latest CRAN version should fix this.

Comment: Wow thanks Tim! I will check this out as soon as I’m back from vacation. Thanks for all the work you do to make awesome OS tools for the rspatial ecosystem

Answer (score 1):

This function used to belong to the package `mapview`. The authors left some of the dependent files in `mapview` in the coding.

I have a fix, though. To see if I was on the right track I forked the repo in Github and made my changes there, installed the package from my repo, and wallah! It works.

In Github, I copied the missing CSS file over from `mapview` and changed the dependencies to `slideview`. You could bring these files into your library manually or install the package from my repo.

> `devtools::install_github('fraupflaume/slideview')`

By the way, you can call the function with `slideview()` or `slideView()`. Both work the same way. (That's from the original package, not me!)

[image]

If you want to see what's missing in the CRAN version, you can get to the directory with `system.file(package = "slideview")`. Within the `slideview` library folders, there's a folder called htmlwidgets. The YAML file in that folder points to the CSS file. (You'll notice it calls for a file that doesn't exist.)

To see the dependencies on `mapview`, use `htmlwidgets::get_dependency("slideview", "slideview")`.

Comment: I've heard back from tim-salabim, who manages (wrote?) the `slideview` package. The changes have been made in Github. I would imagine there will be an update soon (if not already) for the R package. Installing it directly from the main repositories in Github will probably work right now.